# Nginx rewrite module

Tags: nginx

I am having issues to rewrite my URL in nginx

Example:http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/abc 
to 
http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/index.php?q=abc

The location part of nginx.conf is as follows:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
#include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
```

This is returning 500 Internal server error with following errors in my error log file:

```
2016/09/07 14:48:47 [error] 32072#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php" .....
```

I would really appreciate urgent help

Thanks

Comment: What is the complete virtual host configuration? Something causes a redirect loop in the configuration, and it is not here.

Comment: Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: Agreed, you need to show your complete server block. However, if this is a root location `/` then it would cause a rewrite loop because it will change `/abc/` to `/index.php?q=abc` and then falls back to the location and produces `/index.php?q=/index.php?q=abc` and so on... If it's a php location, then the rewrite is happening somewhere else.